# how to append to this json variable

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm a newbie so please...
Im trying to create a python script that uploads files to google drive using access_tokens
im using requests to do this heres my code

```
import json
import requests
from get_acc_tokens import get_access_token as getAT # another script that returns access_tokens

access_tokens = getAT()
headers = {}
para = {
    "name": "update",
}
files = {
    'data': ('metadata', json.dumps(para), 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'),
    'file': {open("update.txt", "rb"),open("update.txt", "rb")}
}
for token in access_tokens:
    headers={"Authorization": token}
    r = requests.post(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart",
        headers=headers,
        files=files
    )
    print(r.text)
```

in this

```
files = {
    'data': ('metadata', json.dumps(para), 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'),
    'file': {open("update.txt", "rb"),open("update.txt", "rb")}
```

how can i add a new file in "file:"
like
`'file: {open('file1.txt';'file2.txt';'file3.txt','rb')`

Comment: Adding elements to a data structure is something covered in any tutorial on that data structure -- a set, in this case.  What result do you expect, and what do you get from your coding attempt?  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each item in `files` will be uploaded as a separate file:

```
files = {
    'file1': open('somefile.txt', 'rb'),
    'file2': open('otherfile.gif', 'rb'),
    'file3': open('anotherfile.zip', 'rb')
}
```

Do you really need each item to have the same key `file`?